# Package web static site to exe nodejs

Tags: node.js, package, static-site

I have static site with some file below:

- index.html
- bundle.js
- images/some file
- some file font, and svg

Problem: I want to build an exe file to serve above file which should run on window.

When install exe file, program will run static site and other component can connect

Please suggest me a for me tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build a node application using `express.js` web server, then you can compile the code and assets into an exe file using the the `pkg` module

Using the pkg module you can bundle your node application to run on windows, mac or linux.

To package your statics files with `pkg` you need to add assets directory to the `package.json` as mentioned in the document

```
"pkg": {
    "assets": "your-assets-dir/**/*"
}
```

Please follow these links,

- [pkg module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)
- [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

If you want to make an installer for windows you may use, [inno script studio](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Electron](https://electronjs.org/). It can serve your static site in a chrome window. But as a Desktop app. You can build this for cross platform and you can also make installer file.